# Visual C++ error with ftd2xx.h

Tags: ftdi

i have make a cpp empty project in Visual Studio 2013.
i add a form (not use it at this time)

in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle;
    FT_STATUS ftStatus;

    ftStatus = FT_Open(0, &ftHandle);
    if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
    {
        cout << "FTDI ERROR TO OPEN\n";
    }

    cout << "fdfd";
    return 0;

}
```

i take this errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000410) "extern "C" unsigned long __stdcall FT_Open(int,void * *)" (?FT_Open@@$$J18YGKHPAPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)    

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" unsigned long __stdcall FT_Open(int,void * *)" (?FT_Open@@$$J18YGKHPAPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ) 

Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

*** In my project path "Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1"

i have put the files:

```
-- FTD2XX.dll
-- ftd2xx.h 
-- ftd2xx.lib
```

also i used this pdf (PAGE 13) to link the ftd2xx.lib file

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_109%20instrustions%20on%20Including%20the%20FTD2xx%20DLL%20in%20VS2008%20Project.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Highly possibly the linker is not looking for the `ftd2xx.lib` in the `Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1` directory, either you put the `.lib` somewhere where Visual Studio can look for it (such as the common LIB directory) or tell VS to look for additional library directories, where you put your `Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1`, or create a common location for all third party library directories and again tell VS to use it.

I think the Project Properties ->Linker -> Additional Directories is the location where you can specify additional directories.

[image]

Comment: the .lib file is already on the "Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project1" path. What more can i do?

Comment: @user3829694 specify the directory in the Additional Library Directories for the project (see screenshot)

Comment: i added the full path of ftd2xx.lib nothing change

Comment: Try: add `#pragma comment(lib, "ftd2xx.lib")` to your `main.cpp`

Comment: same result! same errors. i thought to add the excisting files into the project files its enough... :/

Comment: In the worst case you always can add the library to the project. Project -> Add Existing Item ... and select the library. Does this work?

Comment: do doesn't work! i have add the ftd2xx.lib as excisting item as you say and take same errors... :(

Comment: IT WORKS! i think, its a problem about files, i replace all files (ftd2xx.h , ftd2xx.lib , ftd2xx.dll) with a other new from ftdi site. CDM 2.08.28 WHQL Certified\CDM v2.08.28 Certified\i386 and it work! errors gone... now i want to make the same in Qt